Pole and polar : correspondance between algebraic and geometric definitions
It is easy to define algebraically the notion of polar of a point wrt a projective quadric in finite dimension$^1$. What does this have to do with the harmonic division found in more elementary presentations?

$^1.-$ Let $q$ a quadratic form on a linear space $E$ of finite dimension, with polar form $f$. $$\widehat{f}: x\mapsto f(x,.)$$Let $M=\pi(x)\in P(E)$, where $\pi: E-0\to P(E), \xi\mapsto \mathbb R \xi$.
Polar of $M$ is $\boxed{m=\pi(Ker\widehat{f}(x))}$.https://www.geogebra.org/classic/wdmbaysx
